# Scipy optimise using Nelder-mead

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I have a theoretical question. I am using as optimisation method the ***scipy.optimize.minimize.*** and especially the **Nelder-Mead method**. I have spotted that the results are changing. I am using it to minimise the sum of square differences(SSD) between two images. Running it at different times returns different results, sometimes the error is more than 50% e.g. SSD at first optimisation equals to 150 to the second optimisation 450.
Theoretically, it can be based to the heuristic search method of the algorithm and the non derivative nature of it.

**Is it normal such a big difference?**
I am sorry about the my theoretical question but I am very curious to know/discuss.

Comment: Anyone to discuss it?

Comment: Well, there isn't a lot of information in your question.  Do you mean that when you run your program (exact same program) on the same two image files (exact same image files) that the results are different from run to run? I would also ask why you chose Nelder-Mead given the inefficiencies of the method?

Comment: @JonCuster Hi. My answer to your question is yes to the first one and because I have to but not limited to the second. However,as soon as I noticed that I find it good to know.

Comment: Given the same starting files and guess, classic Nelder-Mead implementations _should_ be entirely deterministic.  However, I have not peered into the guts of the scipy implementation - they may do something weird even though they reference the original paper in their documentation.

Comment: After looking at the scipy code, I conclude it isn't doing anything out of the ordinary.  I can only presume that you have a non-obvious error,

Comment: I don't know image processing, but it's not clear to me what vector you are varying. In any case, it seems that you must be starting with a different (random?) initial vectors, which not surprisingly will send you to different local minima. Perhaps you need to make repeated attempts to find the best starting value?

Comment: The strange thing is that for the specific objective function I give every time the same initials. So the initial vectors are the same. Of course having different initials can produce different results. But in my case the initials are the same.